# opencv error in webcam app

Tags: c, windows, opencv

I am coding an app that captures video from a webcam. I am doing it in C and for Windows. But here is an error that I don't know how to solve it. It's in the variable declaration:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
```

As you can see I am using OpenCV to code my app and this line is to create de connexion between my app and the webcam. Here appears the error. My compiler (MS Visual Studio 2010) says:

> error C2099: El inicializador no es una constante

I have searched in MSDN Microsoft about that error (C2099) but didn't help to fix it.

**PS** Sorry about the spanish version about the error but I haven't download the english version yet.

Comment: did you try what I suggested ?

Comment: Yes, thanks! but unfortunatelly it didn't work with me... i found the solution and posted as a new answer in my post.
See you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
CvCapture* cam = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer but in my case it didnt' work. 
I continued searching a little about how to fix it and I found a solution. In my opinion it's not the optimum solution but it worked with me.
The solution is to change the file from ".c" to ".cpp". This fixes the prolem because the compiler (gcc in my case) invokes dynamic initialization and it's not allowed in pure C.

Thanks a lot folks! :D